# Do the doors in this picture equal 48 houses?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So even after reading through the wiki and looking on websites, I'm having a rough time understanding what villagers consider to be a house. I made a villager breeder and got one baby villager, and now I'm not getting anything. I did some quick arithmetic (9 doors*.35=3.15, I had one villager up by doors and three in breeder) and it seemed that the max villager population, so I added roughly 35 more doors. After doing math with the new doors added (48*.35=16.8) I wondered if the setup I had for the doors made them houses, and as mentioned before, I can't figure out how to know if they're houses or not.

[image]

Do I have this set up wrong, or will the max villager population expand to 16 villagers?

Comment: Link to image is dead.

Comment: ... and because the link to the image is dead, this cannot be answered, so it should be closed as unclear.

Comment: That may be true, but without a clear question, the answer has much less meaning to anyone other than the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad you made it work, but to answer your original question - on the picture I can count 16 valid doors - those are the middle doors on each side that are aligned with the block above the center villager - 4+4+5+3=16.

To check if a door is valid, imagine a line perpendicular to the door that extends 5 blocks on each side of the door. The game counts how many blocks see the sky at each side of the door and compares the two numbers.

In your setup, only the doors aligned with the block above the center villager are valid, because that block obstructs the sky. So on one side of each door (towards the villager) the game counts 4 blocks that can see the sky and on the other side (away from center) there are 5.

To make all doors in your setup valid, you can add 4 more solid blocks to the block above the villager (making a plus sign).

Comment: Is this what you meant? http://imgur.com/aZK4dFZ

Comment: @ExoMute yep :)

Comment: Nine villagers in the breeder, they were breeding so quickly and now nothing. I changed the door design, is it looking good? http://imgur.com/cFjNZ6f I know breeding time is random, but dang I'm one away from having the amount I want :/ I feel like the cobblestone and andesite 'ceiling' should be one block lower

Comment: @ExoMute it seems you problem is no longer with the doors, but a separate issue - you may want to check other parts of the design of the breeding cell as well. Also keep in mind that sometimes it takes a lot of time for villagers to breed even if all conditions are met.

Comment: I think I've already said this before and then went back on it, but I gave it time and now I have 10 villagers in the breeder and 6 in trading slots. I think it's all good now. And seeing as the doors have to be in sunlight, will they not breed at night?

Comment: @ExoMute The game only checks if a block can see the sky, not whether the sun is out. It should work through the night as well,

Answer (score 0):

Hey your setup should work with time. The villager 'mating' rate is a lot different to other animals in the game. A villager has a random chance of creating 'babies' so it might take you longer/shorter than others. The doors you have setup should work just fine as its not a house villagers have to be in but a certain radius to a door. The more doors the better so if you leave your villagers in that machine they should reproduce just fine. :)

Comment: When I threw some carrots in the breeder the hearts started flying, I now have 2-3 babies, so maybe only one villager was willing...¯\_(ツ)_/¯